# How to recognized which uniform grid was clicked?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a Rubikcube that built from  Viewport3D with lots of uniform grid on.
each uniform grid has 6 grids.
how can I recognized from the onClick event on the viewport- which uniform grid was clicked
and on it- which grid was clicked. 
(I tried to perform the on click event on the Viewport children- the grids themselves- but it wasn't supported)

Comment: What do you mean it wasn't supported? It thrown an exception or just didn't work?

Comment: It didn't work, click on the uniform grid never reach the onClick method , in addition I got C# warning

Comment: In order for a control to get a click event, in WPF, is necessary that its background is non null. Otherwise clicks "go through" that object. I would go with catching clicks at grid level, it's quite complicated to get the grid, from the Viewport coordinates, especially if the grid has some transformations.

Comment: I want to know how 3D onClick works???- can anyone help me please???

Comment: @Andrei Pana     first of all thanx-            I know that it's complicated- but is it possible?- what are you suggest me to do?

Comment: Ok, so here it is: Clicks are generally 2D. Your Viewport3D is... 3D. Getting from 3D to 2D it's easy, you just project each point on a plane (basically) which is a many-to-one conversion (more than one point in 3D have just a correspondent point in 2D). To get from 2D to 3D you have to do the reverse of this projection which is starting with 1 point you must to figure what was the original point that projected there. This is not simple and implies which object is in front of which. So I suggest you detect click at grid level. To help you more, I need to see exactly wha you have there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a higher level mouse event handler (e.g. `Window.MouseRightButtonDownEvent`) in combination with `Mouse.DirectlyOver` or `VisualTree.HitTest`.